# triggering end page using java and ApacheClient

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

First of all, I'm not so familiar with web design.

I'm trying to read an HTML page using java.
On some site, every time I get to the end of the page, new information is revealed.

When i receive an html using Apache's HttpClient, I get only the first section of the page.
Is there a way to send some end page signal and get the rest of the page, that appears only when I get to the end of the page in a normal browser?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you're describing is browser dependent.  There are JavaScript based triggers that are being fired based on your visual position within the page.

You'll have to determine what the trigger and subsequent AJAX call are to even attempt to gather more information from the source.